# Python crashes when trying to perform buffer using OSGEO OGR

Tags: python, gis, gdal, ogr, osgeo

I'm trying to run a simple script to manually create some geometry and then perform a buffer on said geometry.  However, python will completely crash whenever I try to perform a Buffer operation.

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
>>> point.AddPoint(1,1)
>>> point.Buffer(1)

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>>
```

I'm running Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should read

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr
>>> point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
>>> point.SetPoint(0, 1, 1) # index, X, Y
>>> point.Buffer(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a new object to hold the buffer geometry. Like:

```
buffer = point.Buffer(1)
```

But it is strange that it crashed completely. No error message?